# sessionStorage deletes itself after reload

Tags: javascript, session, session-storage

I have a problem with this following Code:

```
 "use strict";

let green = "green";
let gold = "gold";
let orange = "orange";

let colors = ["green", "gold", "orange"];
let index = sessionStorage.getItem("color");

if(index == null) {
    index = 0;
}

let button = document.getElementById("click");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(index)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    index++;
    sessionStorage.setItem("color", index);
});
```

why the color is resetting, when I refreh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `document.body.style.backgroundColor` before the click event as well so on initial page load it will pick initial `index` value `0` and apply corresponding colour. Then when the button is clicked `index` value is incremented and new colour is applied.

Upon subsequent refresh updated `index` value will be used from sessionStorage.

```
let green = "green";
let gold = "gold";
let orange = "orange";

let colors = ["green", "gold", "orange"];
let index = sessionStorage.getItem("color");

if (index == null) {
    index = 0;
}

document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];

let button = document.getElementById("click");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(index)  
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    index++;
    sessionStorage.setItem("color", index);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the storage resets on refresh is because you are using session storage. Local storage should be used when trying to persist on refresh.

`myStorage = window.localStorage;`

and then

`myStorage.getItem() or myStorage.setItem()`

Just use it in the same way that you use session storage and you should be fine! More information can be found on the Mozilla Developer Documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Comment: sessionStorage wont reset on page refresh. The data gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Sorry, you are completely right! I have no idea what I was thinking. I will try to help OP now by reproducing the code.

Comment: Session Storage survives over page reloads and restores. You are wrong.